# Is it possible to associate an IAM role with an Aurora cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I would like to load one of my tables in RDS directly onto S3 using `INTO OUTFILE S3 ...`.

I am following the directions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

One of the steps requires that I associate an IAM role with my cluster. But for some reason, that option is grayed out:

[image]

As a result, when I try to use `INTO OUTFILE S3 ...` I still get this error message: `S3 API returned error: Missing Credentials: Cannot instantiate S3 Client`.

I am 99% certain that it worked for me in the past by just following the rules but I can't seem to reproduce it.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a UI bug, my account does not show this new UI. In general, adding roles is a cluster level action. Your screenshot is sensored heavily, so I can't make out if you were trying this on a cluster or on an instance.

The workaround as you've figured out already is to use the AddRoleToCluster Api. If you do think it's a UI bug, do post on AWS Forums or open a support case so that someone addresses it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The console is sometimes not displaying things properly. Use the command in the CLI and it should work fine. Here it is:

`PROMPT> aws rds add-role-to-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier [ENTER_YOUR_CLUSTER] --role-arn [ENTER_THE_ROLE]`

Taken from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/CHAP_AuroraSettingUp.html